# Yup Validation For AutoComplete in Material UI

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, yup

I have an autocomplete that should be required if either of the two fields is true.
My problem is that when I click submit, it outputs `An unhandled error was caught during validation in <Formik validationSchema /> TypeError: You cannot` concat() `schema's of different types: string and object`

```
  category: string().when(['new', 'exist'], {
    is: false,
    then: object({
      id: string(),
      name: string(),
    })
      .nullable()
      .required('field is required'),
  }),
  new: bool().nullable(),
  exist: bool().nullable(),
```

Answer (score 0):

If I’m reading the error message correctly, then it seems that the `string()` you have immediately after `category:`  should be replaced with `object()` instead, i.e.:

```
  category: object().when(['new', 'exist'], {
    is: false,
    then: object({
      id: string(),
      name: string(),
    })
      .nullable()
      .required('field is required'),
  }),
  new: bool().nullable(),
  exist: bool().nullable(),
```

Comment: Its outputting "category must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null`. If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`"

Comment: “...be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`”
in this case I’d bet the “schema” being referred to is of the schema that’s at the “top level” of `category`